# Check if a text file exists

Tags: java, file

I need to pick a text file from a folder and read the data in the file. The file is generated dynamically in that folder in the format "XXX_2010-12-06". So, first i need to check if the file is existing in the folder and if it exists the content of the file should be read.

I have the code to read the content in the text file. I need to provide the path of the file

Can anyone help me in coding this using java...

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what exactly you want help with doing?

Comment: You have a code to read from a file and don't know how to provide the file name to it?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new instance of `File` and initiate it with the path to the file itself.

```
File file = new File("/a/path/to/a/file/TheFile.txt");
```

Once you have your `File` instance created you can check to see if it exists by calling the exists() method inside of `File`.

```
System.out.println(file.exists() ? "The file exists!" : "The file doesn't exist!");
```

I couldn't really understand what you were asking for help with. But if you edit your question to be more clear I will edit my answer to fulfill further answering.

Answer (score 1):

The File class has methods for checking whether a file exists.